# Laravel Crypt value changing on each reload

Tags: php, laravel, mcrypt

I'm trying to use Laravel's [Crypt](http://laravel.com/docs/security#encryption) functionality, to simply store a value in a database and grab it later on to use. However I noticed that I was unable to decrypt this value.

My application key is a random, 32 character string. My cipher is `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128`.
From the PHP info, MCRYPT is installed, and RIJNDAEL_128 is supported.

To test, I do the following on a GET rou:

```
$t = "123456789";

var_dump(Crypt::encrypt($t));
```

See: http://laravel.io/bin/2e9Xr#

On each page refresh, the output is a different value, which is obviously incorrect - however I have no idea why.

I'm using an [EasyPHP](http://www.easyphp.org/) as my dev server. However one thing I have noticed is that the application requests are **significantly** slow on this environment as compared to the production, Apache web server.

This makes me wonder if there is some sort of environment refresh going on each time, potentially resetting the "resources" MCRYPT is using to encrypt, and thus is different each time.

Any clues?

Comment: That's the whole point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is normal behavior. Every Crypt::encrypt call should produce a different output for security reasons.

Crypt is incredibly inefficient for small strings. For example, `Crypt::encrypt("Hello World")` outputs something like the following: `eyJpdiI6Imhnb2hRazVabUNZUnVRVzFBSEExVkE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiTHJ4c05zcjdJZkZwWU1vRVVRMEcwZE5nTUdjQnhyM2RKWTMzSW04b1cxYz0iLCJtYWMiOiIyZjRmNDc3NGEyNGQyOGJjZGQ4MWQxYWViYzI1MjNjZTU0MmY4YTIxYTEyNWVjNDVlZDc4ZWEzNzRmN2QwM2ZiIn0=`

Immediately recognizable as a base 64 string. When decoded, it becomes `{"iv":"hgohQk5ZmCYRuQW1AHA1VA==","value":"LrxsNsr7IfFpYMoEUQ0G0dNgMGcBxr3dJY33Im8oW1c=","mac":"2f4f4774a24d28bcdd81d1aebc2523ce542f8a21a125ec45ed78ea374f7d03fb"}`

Using Crypt, you can encrypt and decrypt large plaintexts easily without worrying about the details. But if you want to store or transmit a lot of separately encrypted entities, then you might want to consider a different approach.

#### So why is it like this?

(Note: the directory structures are valid for Laravel 4.2).

For one, most secure block cipher modes of operation require an [IV (initialization vector)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector), which is a bunch of random bytes with length matching the block size. Using a different IV for every ciphertext is important for thwarting cryptanalysis and replay attacks. But let's look a bit at the actual Crypt code.

Starting with the `config/app.php` aliases array, we see `'Crypt' => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt'`

So we check the `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Support/Facades` directory, and we find `Crypt.php` which says the module accessor name is actually "encrypter". Checking the `config/app.php` providers array shows `'Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider'`.

`vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption` has several files of interest: `Encrypter.php` and `EncryptionServiceProvider.php`. The service provider binds the accessor with a function that creates, configures, and returns an instance of `Encrypter`.

In the `Encrypter` class, we find the encrypt method:

```
public function encrypt($value)
{
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($this->getIvSize(), $this->getRandomizer());
    $value = base64_encode($this->padAndMcrypt($value, $iv));
    // Once we have the encrypted value we will go ahead base64_encode the input
    // vector and create the MAC for the encrypted value so we can verify its
    // authenticity. Then, we'll JSON encode the data in a "payload" array.
    $mac = $this->hash($iv = base64_encode($iv), $value);
    return base64_encode(json_encode(compact('iv', 'value', 'mac')));
}
```

And there you have it. Each time you call `Crypt::encrypt`, it generates a new IV, encrypts the value, creates a [MAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) of the IV and ciphertext, and then returns a base 64 encoded JSON string of an associative array of the IV, MAC, and ciphertext. Each IV will be different, which means every ciphertext and MAC will also be different--even for the same value. Really smart if all plaintexts are large, but pretty impractical for a lot of smaller plaintexts where MACs are unnecessary overhead.

#### tl;dr version:

16 bytes of randomness is generated for every encrypt call, and it cascades into the ciphertext and MAC, all of which is returned in a base 64 encoded JSON associative array. Thus, every Crypt::encrypt call produces different output.

Comment: This is a really good answer, however it doesn't seem that way at first glance, I would first answer the question itself before giving further suggestions. But again, great answer!

Comment: @JaimeGómez Technically, the question was "any clues?", but I suppose I should preifx it with something more direct.

Comment: If this didn't answer the question, I would be very interested to know why -- what would make it a more complete answer. If it did, I'd be interested to know why it was not accepted.

Comment: Hmm, and then how to work around this for cases when I need to use the encrypted value as a key to match it next time? I need predictable values if the input does not change. Is there support for this in Laravel?

Comment: @JustAMartin You won't. You cannot do this without sacrificing security by reusing the IV. However, you can use a hash of the plaintext as the key and hash an input when you need to look up a value.

Comment: There are times when it is mega important to avoid possible hash collisions (no matter how small are the chances), therefore encryption might be one choice to get a predictable key value. But I guess you are right, there are better solutions to generate truly unique key.

Comment: @JustAMartin What would be the point? Why not just use the plaintext as the key if something cryptographically secure is not the goal?

Comment: @JustAMartin If you are worried about collisions, you can use the concatenated outputs of several hashing algorithms as a GUID/key for a table index.

Comment: @Jonathan Voss  Thanks, yes, something like that might work. The point is to obfuscate keys because in my specific case they will be exposed to a web browser and possibly used as localstorage keys.

Answer (score 0):

That's how mcrypt works - http://mnshankar.wordpress.com/2014/03/29/laravel-hash-make-explained/

```
$test = 'test';
$crypted = Crypt::encrypt($test);

echo $crypted.'<br />'; // encrypted string
echo Crypt::decrypt($crypted); // "test"
```